# Unable to insert beyond 4000 character

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I am trying to insert a value(eg O20040601120101SYSONEBNPENDING20040601101010Y00405) into oracle db with the data type long, But I am getting an error saying 
Error report:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01704: string literal too long 
01704. 00000 -  "string literal too long" 
*Cause:    The string literal is longer than 4000 characters. 
*Action:   Use a string literal of at most 4000 characters. 
           Longer values may only be entered using bind variables.
```

I tried using clob also but not able to solve this please help me in this.

Comment: First of all, you should not use `LONG` datatype for columns anymore. Oracle recommends to use LOB datatypes instead - CLOB, NCLOB (based on your requirement)

Comment: The sample data you posted here was inserted successfully in a table with CLOB. Can you post your table definition and the actual data you are trying to insert?

Answer (score 3):

The maximum for one time insertion is 4000 characters (the maximum string literal in Oracle). However you can use the lob function `dbms_lob.append()` to append chunks of (maximum) 
4000 characters to the clob.

[See Here](http://forums.devshed.com/oracle-development-96/how-to-insert-long-datatype-4000-characters-ora-01461-can-bind-137213.html)

[This is useful](https://community.oracle.com/message/3186747?tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a previous comment, you should not use the LONG datatype. It's been deprecated many years ago...

If you are using Oracle 12c, remember that you can use VARCHAR2 datatype too. It's been extended to store up to 32767 bytes!